# Chrome processes still being displayed, even after chrome instance has been closed

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome

I've recently been playing around with the Process class, however, I've come across something a bit peculiar.

When I execute the following code, after I have closed all instances of Chrome:

```
foreach(var p in Process.GetProcesses().OrderBy(p => p.ProcessName))
{
    if(p.ProcessName == "chrome")
        string.Format("{0}: {1} - {2}", p.Id, p.ProcessName).Dump();
}
```

The strange thing is that it still shows multiple chrome processes running. How is this possible?

Comment: One possibility: Some Chrome Add-ons (e.g. Feedly) will cause Chrome to run in the background, even after all instances have been closed. You should see a Chrome icon in the Notification Area of the Taskbar (i.e. the bit by the clock!) if this is the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome per default preserves its processes when they are started by a plugin. So, if you have any plugin installed, this process will remain in memory after you have once started Chrome - even after you have closed the browser.
This is done due to performance reasons - almost all plugins will go through a fairly extensive initialization phase on startup (login, data retrieval etc.). You can change this in Chrome's settings.